# Convert strings in ListBox to List<String>

Tags: delphi, tlist, tlistbox

TListBox component contains a set of rows (strings). How can I get this set as a list TList ? The code examples below, do not give the desired result. (Сode does not compile)

```
MyList  := TList<String>.Create(MyListBox);
MyList  := TList<String>.Create(MyListBox.Items);
MyList  := TList<String>.Create(MyListBox.Items.ToStringArray);
```

Is it possible to do this without using a loop or not?
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this:

```
MyList := TList<string>.Create;
try
  MyList.AddRange(MyListBox.Items.ToStringArray);
  ....
finally
  MyList.Free;
end;
```

If you wanted to assign the items in the constructor you'd need an instance of `TEnumerable<string>`. That's not easy to graft on to `TStrings` from the outside. So I think the above code is probably the cleanest.

Comment: Clean, but not efficient as it could be. `ToStringArray()` allocates and fills a `TArray<String>`, which is then being duplicated in the `TList<String>`. You could just loop through the `TStrings` directly adding the strings to the `TList<string>`, it would take about as much code as you showed here. You could even use a `for in` loop (which `AddRange()` uses internally) since `TStrings` does support enumeration via its `GetEnumerator()` method (that enumerator is just not a `TEnumerable`, though).

Comment: If you had to, you could easily write a class that implements `TEnumerable<string>` and wraps the `TStringsEnumerator` object from `TStrings.GetEnumerator()`, that way it would be compatible with the `TList<string>` constructor.

Comment: @Remy Yes, but how would you manage the lifetime of that instance? Would be fine with ARC, but no good for desktop compilers. Personally I'd extend TList<T>.

Answer (score 3):

David's answer is simple, if you do not mind an extra array being allocated to hold a temp copy of the strings being copied.  If you want to reduce memory usage, especially if the list is large, a loop is better:

```
var
  MyList: TList<String>;
  I: Integer;
begin
  MyList := TList<String>.Create;
  try
    MyList.Capacity := MyListBox.Items.Count;
    for i := 0 to MyList.Capacity-1 do
      MyList.Add(MyListBox.Items[I]);
    ...
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  MyList: TList<String>;
  S: String;
begin
  MyList := TList<String>.Create;
  try
    MyList.Capacity := MyListBox.Items.Count;
    for S in MyListBox.Items do
      MyList.Add(S);
    ...
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

However, if you don't want to loop manually, so I would suggest creating a custom enumerator so you can pass the `TStrings` data directly to `TList<String>` and let it copy the strings for you:

```
type
  TStringsEnumeratorWrapper = class(TEnumerator<String>)
  protected
    FEnum: TStringsEnumerator;
    function DoGetCurrent: String; override;
    function DoMoveNext: Boolean; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AStrings: TStrings);
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

constructor TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.Create(AStrings: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FEnum := AStrings.GetEnumerator;
end;

destructor TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.Destroy;
begin
  FEnum.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.DoGetCurrent: String;
begin
  Result := FEnum.Current;
end;

function TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.DoMoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FEnum.MoveNext;
end;
```

```
type
  TStringsEnumerableWrapper = class(TEnumerable<String>)
  protected
    FStrings: TStrings;
    function DoGetEnumerator: TEnumerator<T>; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AStrings: TStrings);
  end;

constructor TStringsEnumerableWrapper.Create(AStrings: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FStrings := AStrings;
end;

function TStringsEnumerableWrapper.DoGetEnumerator: TEnumerator<T>;
begin
  Result := TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.Create(FStrings);
end;
```

```
var
  MyList: TList<String>;
  Enum: TStringsEnumerableWrapper;
begin
  MyList := TList<String>.Create;
  try
    MyList.Capacity := MyListBox.Items.Count;
    Enum := TStringsEnumerableWrapper.Create(MyListBox.Items);
    try
      MyList.AddRange(Enum);
    finally
      Enum.Free;
    end;
    ...
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Alternatively:

```
type
  TStringsEnumeratorWrapper = class(TObject, IEnumerator<String>)
  protected
    FEnum: TStringsEnumerator;
  public
    constructor Create(AStrings: TStrings);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    function GetCurrent: String;
    function MoveNext: Boolean;
    procedure Reset;
  end;

constructor TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.Create(AStrings: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FEnum := AStrings.GetEnumerator;
end;

destructor TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.Destroy;
begin
  FEnum.Free;
  inherited Destroy;
end;

function TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.GetCurrent: String;
begin
  Result := FEnum.Current;
end;

function TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.MoveNext: Boolean;
begin
  Result := FEnum.MoveNext;
end;

procedure TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.Reset;
begin
  //FEnum.Reset;
end;
```

```
type
  TStringsEnumerableWrapper = class(TObject, IEnumerable<String>)
  protected
    FStrings: TStrings;
  public
    constructor Create(AStrings: TStrings);
    function GetEnumerator: IEnumerator<String>;
  end;

constructor TStringsEnumerableWrapper.Create(AStrings: TStrings);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FStrings := AStrings;
end;

function TStringsEnumerableWrapper.GetEnumerator: IEnumerator<String>;
begin
  Result := TStringsEnumeratorWrapper.Create(FStrings);
end;
```

```
var
  MyList: TList<String>;
begin
  MyList := TList<String>.Create;
  try
    MyList.Capacity := MyListBox.Items.Count;
    MyList.AddRange(TStringsEnumerableWrapper.Create(MyListBox.Items));
    ...
  finally
    MyList.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Granted, not as elegant as David's answer, but enumerators were designed to help make looping through list items easier (and thus allowed the creation of the `for..in` loop syntax).